# Make content at the right most in a div tag

Tags: html, css

I have some html snippet

```
<div id="title">This is title<span id="close">X<span><div>
```

The width of this div is dynamical, maybe 300 600 or 800 px. I want the "X" at the right most of the div at the same line. So write a css like below:

```
#close
{
   margin-right:10px;
}
```

But it does not work. If I want to implement it, what should I config?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning.

```
#title {position: relative; width: 300px}
#close {position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px} /* adjust based on required margin */
```

But keep in mind that the absolutely positioned content is outside the box model and it may overlap the content within the `title` div. You need to set appropriate padding/margin to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="title"><div class="float-right"><span id="close">X</span></div>This is title</div>
```

and the class

```
.float-right{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: And if you want that, the X will be some what 10 or 20 px right of the extreme right, use margin-right in the float-right class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="title">This is title<div><span id="close">X<span></div><div>
```

and the styling:

```
#title div {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  clear: none;
}
```

Or you could get rid of the span entirely and just use the div, make it maybe 20px wide and style it with a different color so it would look more like a button.

Me, I'd use a graphic in an img for the close button, but to each his own.

Alternate arrangement:

```
<div id="title"><div style="width:20px"><span id="close">X<span></div>This is title<div>
```

Comment: Hi, the "X" is at the right most now, but it's not at the same line with the title, it goes to the second line.

Comment: Give the div a width of, say, 20px. That should do it. Make sure you float:right and clear:none as well. You can also try putting the div *first* in the containing div and the text second.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the HTML in your question:

- The CSS property "margin-right" gives you 10px of space to the right of your element, outside the border. Instead, you want to be using float:right (and a div instead of a span, since floating works with block elements only)
- Your tags are not closed (use `<div></div>` instead of `<div><div>`)

To achieve what you are after, try the following:

```
<div id="title">
    This is title <div id="close">X</div>    
</div>
```

With the following CSS

```
#close 
{ 
 float:right;
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend getting the Firebug (www.getfirebug.com) for Mozilla Firefox, which will allow you to inspect the html/css of your page and change it on the fly. Alternatively, you can also use the Developer Tools in IE8 (hit F12), but I personally find Firebug the easiest to use.

Comment: Hi, the "X" is at the right most now, but it's not at the same line with the title, it goes to the second line.